# composer update returned with error code 1

Tags: installation, scripting, composer-php, failed-installation

on composer update i got this error

`Script [ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:prepare handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 1`

It says me, that the command $PHP_BINARY written wrong or couldnt find.

this scripts are added:

```
scripts:
  pre-install-cmd     
  pre-update-cmd
  post-install-cmd
  post-update-c
```

My php-version
 `8.1.13`
System:
`shopware 6`

if i use `--no-scripts` , then the composer update is succesfully. But
I don't know what the consequences are.

Comment: Sounds like any of the scripts is not running properly. What happens if you run it manually?